# How to use morgan in SPDY > Express.JS > Next.JS setup to capture and show detailed request paths?

Tags: reactjs, express, next.js, efk, morgan

I am using SPDY server for HTTP/2 for my React.JS / Next.JS application. Unfortunately this solution needs to use Express.JS and therefore this is what I do to have request logging:

```
    // Init the Next app:
    const app = next({ dev, dir: __dirname })
    const handle = app.getRequestHandler()
const options = {
  key: fs.readFileSync('server.key'),
  cert: fs.readFileSync('server.crt'),
}
app.prepare().then(() => {
    const expressApp = express()
    const format = json({
      IP: ':remote-addr',
      User: ':remote-user',
      Timestamp: ':date[clf]',
      Method: ':method',
      Path: ':url',
      Protocol: 'HTTP/:http-version',
      Status: ':status',
      ContentLength: ':res[content-length]',
      Referrer: ':referrer',
      Agent: ':user-agent',
      ResponseTime: ':response-time ms',
    })
    expressApp.use(
      logger(format, {
        stream: accessLogStream,
      })
    )
  expressApp.all('*', (req, res) => {
    return handle(req, res)
  })
   const server = spdy.createServer(options, expressApp)
  server.listen(port, (err) => {
    if (err) {
      apm.captureError(err)
      console.error('Failed to start server', err)
      process.exit(1)
    } else {
      console.log(`HTTP/2 server listening on port: ${port}`)
    }
  })
})
```

However, I get most of the request paths showing up as "Others" in my EFK logging dashboard:
[image]
How can I get the detailed request paths going into the Next.JS application?